# Melting Laptop Power Supply Tip

Tags: laptop, power-supply

Several (6-7) months ago, my laptop power supply cord got a cut in it and stopped working. Having gotten cheap (and short) power supplies in the past, I decided to buy 2 brand new ones from the manufacturer (ASUS).

Now, I used my laptop a little less than usual between February and March. During that time I noticed a few times that the power supply, even though plugged in, did not provide power. Often the computer would just off on me. I figured it was just that one power supply being bad. I had left the alternate at my parent's house in another state and asked them to ship it to me.

Now, at work the other day I wanted to get a file off the of hard disk. So I booted it up, knowing that it had a low battery, plugged it in. During the first 2 minutes of use, I was told that the battery was low and I should plug it in. I unplugged it, inspected the end (Being plugged in, this was suspicious), and decided I shouldn't plug it back in-- **the plastic on the tip was melting from the heat of the metal on the tip.**

The computer had simply booted up and I had the file-manager open. It had not been on for more than 10 hours.

Now I know that computers tend to get pretty hot. However, the melting point of plastic is usually above 200C.. so that's much hotter than the computer should be generating.

I went and bought a THIRD power supply. This time a universal one from Best Buy (it was very fast to buy and test). I tried it out on the computer and it's tip is melting as well. My older laptop that uses the universal power supply uses it perfectly (has been about a week and a part of use now). I have tried using the computer without the battery, with the same effect.

Obviously, this is not a problem with the power supply. My room mate and I being trained computer techs were contemplating taking the computer apart and desoldering and resoldering on the power tip. (The computer is about 6 months out of its 2-year warranty).

We're hoping that will correct the issue as I would prefer to devote my money on a Good Desktop rather than yet ANOTHER $1200+ laptop. Is there any thing I'm missing here that might cause the the tip on the power unit to melt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have problems with the power connector of your laptop. It somehow has higher resistance than the normal, and laptops tend to consume high currents, it generates a lot of heat. Just bring your laptop to a service, and tell them your problem. They will change your power connector.

Answer (score 0):

Your power jack might be bad or some other components (fuses, etc.). If you have some soldering experience and can use a multimeter, jump in and see what happens.

I use [this](http://www.lowes.com/pd_239400-16878-60273_4294857616_4294937087?productId=1067929&pl=1&currentURL=/pl_Screwdrivers%2Band%2BNut%2BDrivers_4294857616_4294937087_?cm_cr=Hand) Kobalt multi-bit screwdriver and a magnetic tray (Lowes - tool section or Walmart - car section) together with a digital camera to take apart laptops. I place the screws in counterclockwise circle in the tray in the order that I remove them. You can rub a magnet in one direction (not in circles) on the tip of the screwdriver to magnetise it (which does *not* harm computers [reference Scott Mueller's materials] - people who say otherwise are ignorant).

To find precise directions for your laptop Google the terms "[YOUR LAPTOP MODEL] disassembly" or "breakdown". Read through it thouroughly, but *never* trust it entirely. You can buy a new DC power jack off of Ebay or use Google to find another provider.

I would estimate the cost of the tools and jack at around $40-60 without a soldering iron. A soldering iron (and materials - solder, flux, desoldering braid, etc.) runs $20-120 depending on what you buy. If you haven't soldered before you might want to consider passing on this and taking it to a computer repair shop.

Hope this helps!